# Display: Table-cell with set width/ cells on multiple lines

Tags: html, css, height, css-tables, tablerow

I have a series of divs that in mobile are supposed to display at 50% of the page width. However, they are also supposed to be the same height (or at least, each pair of two divs next to each other should be the same height). I would prefer to do this just with css and not javascript. This was my intial code:

```
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
<div/>

.box-container{
    width:100%;
}
.box{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
```

This gives me a box of divs two-per-row, but they are not equal height. So I changed it to a table:

```
.box-container{
    display:table-row;
}
.box{
    display:table-cell;
    float:none;
    position:relative;
    width: 50%;
}
```

However, the 50% width doesn't seem to matter and all of the divs display on the same line. How can I make them each be 50% and break to a new line?

Comment: are you married to the idea of using a table layout? are there issues with using flex?

Comment: No, I can do that, I'm just not very familiar with flex. I'm fine with any solution that puts two boxes per row, and makes every two boxes the same height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**. Disclaimer: This does not answer specifically how to do it with table layout, however since OP is flexible with solution, this is what I would recommend.

The reason your div's height vary, is because since you didn't specify a height, it is depending on the content inside of it. You can do many things, like set the `min-height` or `max-height` properties, or even simply set the `height` property. However, if you don't know the height or what's potentially going to be in the div's, you can take advantage of flexbox.

Although, this doesn't support legacy browsers, this is just one way of accomplishing what your asking:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

/*just for demonstration */
.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.box:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">Box 1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Taking advantage of `align-items: stretch`:

> Flex items are stretched such that the cross-size of the item's margin box is the same as the line while respecting width and height constraints.

---

References:

[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution is better if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve.

Using floats, don't forget to clear them, also `height: 100%` on box should do the trick.

```
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
<div/>

.box-container{
    width:100%;
}
.box-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.box{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmpx5w2s/1/

Comment: I don't think that will work because I cannot put a fixed height on the container, the height depends on the contents of the inner boxes